# Use and meaning of "Would" in following sentence

Tags: subjunctives, will-would

As part of my effort to understand use of "would", I came across below text on internet.

> I need a translator (junior translators welcome) to proofread/revise a text. Must be a native speaker. Please email me to get more details.
>   I am looking for someone responsible and serious. **I would send you
>   the document Friday night or Saturday morning, and I would need it for
>   Saturday evening**.

As per my understanding, here "would" is used as 2nd condition sentence where condition is unlikely to happen.

I believe in above sentence instead of "would", use of "will" is a better choice.

Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It is actually a hypothetical situation, but the **if** clause is implied, rather than stated explicitly:

> [If you were my translator,] I would send you the document Friday night or Saturday morning, and I would need it for Saturday evening.

The hypothetical situation doesn't need to be unlikely to happen. This mode of speech can also be used to discuss possibilities (as in this sentence) or to politely make suggestions:

> If you were to buy me an ice cream, I would be very happy